# Datagridview will not display the values. The correct number of rows is displayed but no text appears in the columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My problem is that when the values are loaded into my `datagridview` from the database, the datagridview will not display the values/information. The correct number of rows is displayed but no text appears in the columns.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace Movie_Memorizer2
 {
    class clsDB
    {
    static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source");


    public static DataTable franDB(string str)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            if (!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)) conn.Open(); 

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = str;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            da.Fill(dt);

            da = null; 
            cmd = null;
            conn.Close(); 

        }

        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            string felet = ex.Message; //mer kod här om man vill
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

class frmMovie - this is where I call the method "franDB" in the class clsDb above

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace Movie_Memorizer2
 {

 public partial class frmMovie : FormBase
 {
    public frmMovie()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormMovie_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        dgvMovies.DataSource = clsDB.franDB("SELECT * FROM Movie ORDER BY name");

    }
```

Comment: Did you check the `AutoGenerateColumns` property for the grid, it should be `true`

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see if an error happens in `franDB` method?

Answer (score 0):

After setting the DataSource, add:

```
dvgMovies.DataBind()
```

Comment: DataBind is for web not for winforms DataGridView

Comment: [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) in System.Windows.Forms.Control don't have a method called DataBind

Comment: In some versions no; in other versions yes.